# How to rerun failed test from where they instead of from beginning? (TestNG)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Is there any way to re run the failed testcase from the page where it got failed instead of running the testcase from beginning in Selenium Java ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not by default. It could be possible, but you need to store which code can be skipped and somehow put this logic in your tests. This would create a pretty complex test-framework.

Make your tests shorter :) WebDriver tests should run in seconds, not minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [TestNG documentation for rerunning](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning), Every time tests fail in a suite, TestNG creates a file called `testng-failed.xml` in the output directory. This XML file contains the necessary information to rerun only these methods that failed, allowing you to quickly reproduce the failures without having to run the entirety of your tests. So, you just need to do like this

```
java -classpath testng.jar;%CLASSPATH% org.testng.TestNG -d test-outputs test-outputs\testng-failed.xml
```

This is the manual approach, for the automatic way you need to implement a login for Retry Test using TestNG Listener `IRetryAnalyzer` to handle max-retry count and all.
There are many similar threads that have been discussed on same topic.

[Restart failed test case automatically in TestNG/Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713564/restart-failed-test-case-automatically-in-testng-selenium),
[Rerun a test class when it fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25788524/1976848)

Hope this helps!!